# Javascript file object - Can we slice backward with negative values?

Tags: javascript, slice

We use file.slice(start,end) to slice a chunk of a file ( to be fed to FileReader ). I want to read from the end, How can we do this ?

```
        var file = files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function(evt){
            if(evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE){
                console.log(a);
            }
        }
        var blob = file.slice(0,5); // ---->  ( I want to read 2 bytes from backward, For now I do, file.slice(fileSize-2). Is there another way guys ? )
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

Comment: By slize, do you mean **slice**?

Comment: Have you tried using a negative *start* value?

Comment: Can you please provide the code you tried?

Comment: Are you using an ArrayBuffer to read the file? Can you include your code and provide an example to clarify what "read from the end" means?

Comment: Thanks @trincot, I was pointing to the Blob.slice, which the File object inherits. Its here at, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File .

Comment: As Robba mentioned, you can provide negative values to go backwards. Both start and end paramaters support this

Comment: Thanks, Robba and Dogoku, I did not notice the documentation says about negative values.